# C++ reverse char array by only pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, reverse

I have written this code to reverse a string which is pointed by char pointer `arr` and we need to reverse the characters without using any function or length or any DS. Just using char pointers and only char variables. This is the code but it gives error

> CodeBlocks has stopped working

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *arr = "ABCDE"; // string
    char *ans = arr; // another pointer
    char tmp;
    char *s = arr;
    while (*ans != '\0')
        ans++;
    ans--; // now (*ans) is the last character (not null char)
    while (arr < ans)
    {
        tmp=*arr;
        *arr=*ans;
        *ans=tmp;
        arr++; // increment arr by 1
        ans--; // decrement ans by 1
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl; // print reversed string
}
```

Comment: Change `char *arr` to `char arr[]`

Comment: In C++ string literals are *constant* arrays of characters. Attempting to modify one leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What part of this is exact duplicate to those linked posts though? Also he want it to be a pointer only solution so I don't think char[] is the solution. Anyways if you just need the output, you could replace your loop content with cout << *--ans;